# React native and Firebase real time database querying gives null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm using firebase real time database with react native. Here I'm trying to login the user based on email address.

```
firebase.database().ref('Users')
      .startAt(email)
      .endAt(email)
      .once('value', function (snap) {
        console.log(snap)
        console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val())
      });
```

I have number of documents inside the `Users` collection. I'm trying to fetch the document which contains the email address I'm passing inside `email` variable. But in the console I'm getting the value as null.

```
accounts matching email address, null
```

I'm giving proper email address in the variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Works when I'm trying to fetch everything from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `equalTo()` to query according to the email address:

```
firebase.database().ref('Users')
      .orderByChild("email")
      .equalTo(email)
      .once('value', function (snap) {
        console.log(snap)
        console.log('accounts matching email address', snap.val())
      });
```

Assuming you have the following db:

```
Users
  randomId
       email : email_here
```

Comment: Yes! It worked. Thanks. I'm getting an object as the document. By the way is this is the proper way to querying to Firebase or is there any efficient way?

Comment: yes this is correct but if you are using firebase authentication then you can use the uid instead of `randomId` and access it without query